# how to calculate the time for retransmission in slotted Aloha

Tags: telecommunication, wireless-communication

I need to configure my code to make retransmission in slotted Aloha in case of collision, how to choose the timer ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the other guy (who you collided with) will also try to retransmit. So you need a random factor.

You can start by waiting 1 to 16 slots and if you collide again (6.25% chance both parties picked the same slot) then you wait for 1 to 32 slots and so on.

Comment: do u mean choose random number between 1 and 16

Comment: @EK.Technology yeah. The more slots you provide the less chance for repeated collision but the longer the potential delay.